# Accessing ViewModel data in View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I just want to ask if it's OK to access the `ViewModel's` data in the `View` backend?

Basically I just need a check to see if a `ViewModel's` property is set (which gets set when the user selects something), and if it's not I'll just redirect the user to another `View` telling him he needs to select something first. Is this a poor-design practice or is it OK, just for a minor check like this? Really don't want to implement a static class and extrapolate the data to it, and check it instead.

Another question tightly related to this, is can I call a method from the `View` (when the `View` is closing), that unregisters that particular `ViewModel` from the IoC container (this `ViewModel` isn't singleton). The alternative is to send a message from the View to the `ViewModel` when the `View` is closing, and when the `ViewModel` gets that message it unregisters itself. The problem I'm trying to solve with this is that, every time that `ViewModel` is requested it has to be a new one, but my IoC container caches them, making my program a memory hog. All of the `ViewModels` get released on application exit, meaning x `ViewModels` will still exist in the cache even though they're most likely not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I just need a check to see if a `ViewModel's` property is set (which gets set when the user selects something), and if it's not I'll just redirect the user to another `View` telling him he needs to select something first. Is this a poor-design practice or is it OK, just for a minor check like this?

It does not seem to be wrong to check the value of some `ViewModel` property and reflect the changes on the `View` side. The `View` state could be "bound" to the `ViewModel` state by the WPF data binding mechanism: `Binding`, `Triggers` (`Trigger`, `DataTrigger`, `EventTrigger`), `Commands` (including `EventToCommand`), etc.

But sometimes it is useful to handle `ViewModel` state change by the `ViewModel` itself using UI Services. For example, `IWindowService` interface can be introduced to allow to open windows from the context of the `ViewModel` implementation.

> Another question tightly related to this, is can I call a method from the `View` (when the `View` is closing), that unregisters that particular `ViewModel` from the IoC container (this `ViewModel` isn't singleton).
>
> ...
>
> The problem I'm trying to solve with this is that, every time that `ViewModel` is requested it has to be a new one, but my IoC container caches them, making my program a memory hog. All of the `ViewModels` get released on application exit, meaning x `ViewModels` will still exist in the cache even though they're most likely not needed.

It seems to be strange that the described dependency container "cache effect" exists when the registration is specified as "resolve per call behavior" (not "singleton behavior"). Please check that the registration is specified as "resolve per call behavior" (for example, `PerResolveLifetimeManager` in terms of [Unity Container Lifetime Managers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)).

### Update

The `ViewModel` lifetime problem exists because SimpleIoC container is used.
I would like to recommend using another dependency injection container (with appropriate lifetime management) to make the implementation less complex and error-prone.

But, if there is a **strong need** to use SimpleIoC container, some kind of the `ViewModel` lifetime management can be implemented using:

- `SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ViewModel>(key);` method call to resolve an instance of `ViewModel`;
- `SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(key);` to un-register the instance when it is no longer needed (`Closed` event, etc).

The implementation can be found here: [answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16997280/490018), [answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014035/490018).

Comment: I'm using SimpleIoC, included in Mvvm Light. It's really barebones. You can't specify behaviour other than immediate creation / on first call. It had everything I need, plus I was using Mvvm Light in the application, other dependency container libraries seemed to add unnecessary complications (in the scope of my project). [docs here!](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/e2774a68-2132-6ab6-61a4-2eb3e8ae811b.htm)

Comment: @RexGrammer, could you please post the source code to demonstrate how SimpleIoC is used?

Comment: You create a static class that's the ViewModelLocator, add it to the app resources. ViewModelLocator's constructor:  `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);`                     `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();` Then you just expose a property `public MainViewModel Main { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(); } }` to which you bind a view's datacontext.

Comment: [SO Link - Info about SimpleIoC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795596/how-to-use-mvvmlight-simpleioc) (incl. examples)

Comment: SimpleIoC seems to be *so simple* that it introduces complication because of "caching" (as limitation): it is required to implement registration and un-registration of the `ViewModels` to support "resolve per call behavior". I would like to recommend using another dependency injection container. Please see [the similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342294/simpleioc-can-it-provide-new-instance-each-time-required).

Comment: So it's a the tools fault. I'll have to take all this into consideration next time I undergo a project like this. But at this point it's out of the question to switch dependency injection containers, so I guess I'll just have to stick with what I have and make due. Thanks.